# MVC Form Submit - Redirecting to an action that is not accessible from the browser directly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am learning MVC 3 after hours right now and last night I ran into an issue that seems like it would be very simple to solve but I can't seem to locate a solution for it.

I have a simple contact form.  The end user fills out the form and submits it. When they submit the form I redirect the end user to a different action in the same controller which renders an "inquiry submitted" page/view which is basically a "Thank you page".

The controller is setup like so.

```
public ActionResult ContactUs()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactInfo contactInfo)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return View();
     }

     //perform some business logic

     return RedirectToAction("InquirySubmitted",contactInfo);


}

 public ActionResult InquirySubmitted(ContactInfo contactInfo)
 {
    return View(contactInfo);
 }
```

**The problem:** 
I do not want end users navigating directly to the InquirySubmitted action via the browser.
I only want the ContactUs action in the controller to be able to send users to the InquirySubmitted View.

I have attempted to make the InquirySubmitted action private so that only the controller can call it like so:

```
private ActionResult InquirySubmitted(ContactInfo contactInfo)
```

But this produces an error which I fully understand because I am forcing the browser to request InquirySubmitted by using RedirectToAction().

So my question is simply: What is the best "MVC 3 style" solution to this issue.

Comment: @Splash-X - That's one option he could do, but if the user refreshes the page for some reason, it will re-submit the contact request.  You would typically use a Post-Redirect-Get pattern to solve that.

Comment: @Splash-X Yes the solution does technically work thank you. This is an option. But as Mystere Man states pressing F5 causes a refresh which fires off all of my business logic again and as he stated this solution breaks the PRG pattern so I was hoping for a solution which is a bit more ideal.  As of right now, the only solution I see to this is an answer posted below which is to use session to see if an end user came from the contact page and if not send them back to it if they try to access InquirySubmitted directly. This solution would be identical to the web forms solutions.

Comment: @Matt I agree, but your request was so that the end user could not request the URL. By creating an action they can always request the URL. Ek0nomik is right, you can use a session variable to track if they are supposed to be able to view the page. You could also look at the Referring URL and check to see if it is the form page, and if so, display the view otherwise return a Redirect to the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put logic in your InquirySubmitted ActionResult in order to prevent users from viewing the page if they are not supposed to.

You are already passing the InquirySubmitted method your model (ContactInfo).  Could you simply inspect the data passed to the method and if it is absent then redirect the user to an error page (or some other page of your choice)?

An alternate solution would be to set a boolean in session that indicates that the user completed the "ContactUs" form.  Then you could check for that session object within InquirySubmitted.

Comment: Yes thank you for this answer.  Yes, I can do this for certain and this will work. But, I was just wondering if there is an "MVC 3 specific feature" that I am missing that can handle this without me having to insert tracking data in session perhaps.

Comment: @Matt - How secure do you need this to be?  My other suggestion of inspecting the `ContactInfo` model would also work.  But, that model is really just boiling down to GET parameters, so those could be forged.

Comment: This solution is the same solution you would use in a web form app but still seems to be the best. Effective and easy.                     public ActionResult InquirySubmitted(ContactInfo contactInfo)
        {

            if (Session["ContactFormSubmitted"] == "true")
            {
                Session["ContactFormSubmitted"] = "false";
                return View(contactInfo);
                
            }
            else
                return RedirectToAction("ContactUs");
        }

Comment: You should use TempData.  TempData is a specialized collection that (out of the box) relies on Session but only keeps the key/value pair until it's read once.  Ideal for messages, wizard navs and other pages that require a sequence, but that will be redirected to.  Just shove some variable in TempData before redirecting to the action, then read it back from TempData in the other action.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would have to say.. Who cares if someone can navigate directly to the Inquiry submitted page?  Is there any confidential information, or something sensitive there?  If not, so what?  What does it hurt?

However, if you're determined to do so.  The answer to your question of "How to make an action not accessible directly from the browser" is that You can simply use `Html.Action()` to render the page, and then decorate the action method with a `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.

This doesn't actually solve the problem though, since making the action indirectly accessible only answers your question, not solves your problem.  Ultimately, you need to redirect the user to a url to load the page, so you will need some logic that determines if they can view the page or not.  This is

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this still applies in MVC3, but in MVC2 it worked.

your global.asax file has your url structuring in it.  You can add your InquirySubmitted to the list of urls that isn't accessible there.